# Reverse-Regex: Xeger for C#

Tags: library, c#, regex

There is [Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/), a library for finding valid input to a regular expression. That means, it does the opposite of what you usually do with Regex. I'm using this for fuzz-testing at the moment.

I'm looking for a similar library in C#, preferably .NET 4.0. It should work on Windows Vista SP2 and later.

It needs to work with the MS toolchain, not necessarily with Mono.

It may be commercial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was asked on Stack Overflow but it might get closed as off-topic since it is a tool recommendation.

The answer by [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361460/roman) was:

> From what I could find, [Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) is the most popular solution, but it is in Java.
>
> However, apparently there is a C# version: [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare).
> If you read the description, they say that Xeger was partially ported into Fare application, but not fully.